# What is the ? for in a JSX React variable declaration?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In the following JSX declaration:

var itemClass = this.props.completed ? 'item completed' : 'item'

What is the purpose of the "?"

Answer (score 1):

```
var itemClass = this.props.completed ? 'item completed' : 'item'
```

is the equivalent of

```
if (this.props.completed == true)
    itemClass = 'item completed'
else
    itemClass = 'item'
```

it's the **ternary conditional operator**:

```
Condition ? Result if True : Result if false
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!